# Indexing in plot x-axis label in for loop

Tags: r, loops, plot, label

I am making plots with a for loop in the form of

```
for(i in 1:10){
plot(matrix.X, ylab=expression(beta[i]))
}
```

This code only labels each of the 10 plots with Beta_i, however I would like the ylabs to be Beta_1,...,Beta_10. How shall I label the plots? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:10){
  plot(matrix.X, ylab=paste0("beta_", i)) # you need the paste function
}
```